# Nonlinear ODE solver

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I'm working on a non-linear differential equation solver. I'm able to get to the general solution but not the specific solution. When I try to find the integration constants, I get the error: E_x not callable and that my solution is classified as a list so I can't substitute anything into it.

Here is my code:

```
j, u, eps, V_0, d = sympy.symbols("j, u, eps, V_0, d")
E = sympy.Function("E_x") (x) #set up symbolic solver

Vi = sympy.Derivative(E)

ode = E*Vi+j/(u*eps)    #define the differential equation


E_sol = sympy.dsolve(ode)   #solve

print(E_sol) #print general solution

ics = {E(0):0}

C_eq = E_sol.subs(x,0).subs(ics)
C_ = sympy.solve(C_eq)
```

I get the callable error on 
`ics = {E(0):0}`
and the list error on 
`C_eq = E_sol.subs(x,0).subs(ics)`
The example in the book that I have (Numerical Python) solves a linear ODE and doesn't get this error. Is there a different way to solve nonlinear DE or to define E as callable and E_sol as not a list?

Answer (score 1):

A function `f` can be called as in `f(x)` but you can't call a function that has been called as in `f(x)(1)` -- you need to use subs. Also, Python list doesn't understand `subs` but the things inside the list do. So you either have to iterate over the list and make your substitution on the elements of the list that understand substitution *or* you can convert your list into a SymPy container that does understand substitution, e.g.

```
>>> [x, 1/x].subs(x, 2) # no
>>> L = [x, 1/x]
>>> [i.subs(x, 2) for i in L]  # yes
[2, 1/2]
>>> from sympy import Tuple
>>> Tuple(*L).subs(x, 2)
(2, 1/2)
```

So using those two ideas and defining `x`, your code gives

```
import sympy
x, j, u, eps, V_0, d = sympy.symbols("x, j, u, eps, V_0, d")
E = sympy.Function("E_x") (x) #set up symbolic solver
Vi = sympy.Derivative(E)
ode = E*Vi+j/(u*eps)    #define the differential equation
E_sol = sympy.dsolve(ode)   #solve
ics = {E.subs(x,0):0}
C_eq = [i.subs(x,0).subs(ics) for i in E_sol]
C_ = sympy.solve(C_eq)

>>> print(E_sol) #print general solution
[Eq(E_x(x), -sqrt(C1 - 2*j*x/(eps*u))), Eq(E_x(x), sqrt(C1 - 2*j*x/(eps*u)))]
>>> print(C_)
[{C1: 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Th problem is that you've used

```
E = Function('E')(x)
```

Try this interactively:

```
In [12]: E = Function('E')                                                                                                                                    

In [13]: E                                                                                                                                                    
Out[13]: E

In [14]: E(x)                                                                                                                                                 
Out[14]: E(x)

In [20]: E(1)                                                                                                                                                 
Out[20]: E(1)

In [15]: E(x)(1)                                                                                                                                              
...
TypeError: 'E' object is not callable

In [16]: E = Function('E')(x)                                                                                                                                 

In [17]: E                                                                                                                                                    
Out[17]: E(x)

In [18]: E(1)                                                                                                                                                 
...
TypeError: 'E' object is not callable
```

It is generally better to define `E = Function('E')` and then use `E(x)` throughout the rest of your code.

Also `dsolve` can handle the initial conditions for you so with that in mind:

```py
import sympy

j, u, eps, V_0, d = sympy.symbols("j, u, eps, V_0, d")
E = sympy.Function("E")

ode = E(x)*E(x).diff(x) + j/(u*eps)    #define the differential equation

E_sol = sympy.dsolve(ode, ics={E(0):0})   #solve with initial conditions

print(E_sol) #print particular solution
```

That gives

```
In [25]: E_sol                                                                                                                                                
Out[25]: 
⎡               _______                _______⎤
⎢              ╱ -j⋅x                 ╱ -j⋅x  ⎥
⎢E(x) = -√2⋅  ╱  ───── , E(x) = √2⋅  ╱  ───── ⎥
⎣           ╲╱   eps⋅u             ╲╱   eps⋅u ⎦
```